# Find all possible Jordan forms

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, jordan-normal-form

Let $A \in M_3(\mathbb{C})$, and:
$\frac1{12}A=[A^2-7A+16I_3]^{-1}$

Find all possible Jordan Forms of A
(no need to show different block orders)

I was thinking of Algebraic manipulations such as:
$12A^{-1}=A^2-7A+16I_3 \space/*A$

$12I_3=A(A^2-7A+16I_3)\space/*A$

$A(A^2-7A+16I_3)-12I_3=0 \space/$

$A^3-7A^2+16A-12I_3=0$

$(A-3)(A-2)^2$

Meaning Eigenvalues are 2 and 3.

Notice that Geometric Multiplicity of $\lambda_2$ can be 1 or 2.

So biggest Joran block can be of the sizes 1 or 2

finally:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

or

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

I'd be happy if you could confirm my solution.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i will type it... As in the later form of the question, we know that $A$ satisfies $p(A)=0$ for 
$$
p(x)=(x-2)^2(x-3)\ .
$$
So the minimal polynomial of $A$ is a divisor of the above $p$, it is thus one among:
$$
(x-2)\ ,\ 
(x-3)\ ,\
(x-2)(x-3)\ ,\
(x-2)^2\ ,\
(x-2)^2(x-3)\ .
$$
Correspondingly we have the possible Jordan forms:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2&&\\&2&\\&&2
\end{bmatrix}\ ,\
\begin{bmatrix}
3&&\\&3&\\&&3
\end{bmatrix}\ ,\
\begin{bmatrix}
2&&\\&3&\\&&3
\end{bmatrix}\ ,\
\begin{bmatrix}
2&&\\&2&\\&&3
\end{bmatrix}\ ,\
\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&\\&2&\\&&2
\end{bmatrix}\ ,\
\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&\\&2&\\&&3
\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$

Comment: Ok, got it. I thought for no reason, i got the Characteristic polynomial, and since it's just a given equation, the minimal polynomial doesn't have to contain all of the solutions for the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: from $\frac1{12}A=[A^2-7A+16I_3]^{-1}$ we get $A^3-7A^2+16A-12I_3=0$, hence the char. polynomial of $A$ is given by

$p(x)=x^3-7x^2+16x-12$.

Then show that $p(x)=(x-2)^2(x-3)$.

Can you proceed with these informations concerning the eigenvalues of $A$ ?

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $A$ is a  divisor of the above $p$. The characteristic polynomial may also be $(x-2)^3$ or $(x-3)^3$ or...

Answer (score 0):

You obtained $A^3-7A^2+16A-12I_3=0$ therefore the minimal polynomial $m_A$ divides the polynomial $x^3-7x^2+16x-12=(x-2)^2(x-3)$.

The options for the minimal polynomial and respective Jordan forms are:

- $m_A(x) = x-2$
  $$\pmatrix{2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2}$$
- $m_A(x) = (x-2)^2$
  $$\pmatrix{2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2}$$
- $m_A(x) = x-3$
  $$\pmatrix{3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3}$$
- $m_A(x) = (x-2)(x-3)$
  $$\pmatrix{2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3} \quad\text{ or} \quad\pmatrix{2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3}$$
- $m_A(x) = (x-2)^2(x-3)$
  $$\pmatrix{2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3}$$

Note that in all these cases the matrix $A^2 -7A+16I_3$ is invertible because the polynomial $x^2-7x+16$ has complex zeros, so $\frac1{12}A=[A^2-7A+16I_3]^{-1}$ is indeed equivalent to $A^3-7A^2+16A-12I_3=0$.